# Plurals have two meaning?

Tags: syntax

For example, "pencils have a cap" means each pencil has a cap and a group of pencils has a cap?
If so, how can I differenciate these two meaning naturally?????

Comment: Why are you using five question marks? One will suffice just fine.

Comment: "Pencils have a cap." by itself is making a statement of belief (or based on actual knowledge) that pencils *in general* have caps. Another example, "Cars have a steering wheel."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Each** of the pencils has a cap.
>
> **All** of the pencils have a cap.

Note that "each of" is singular, but "all of" is plural.  [More information on which *indefinite pronouns* are singular and which are plural.](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000027.htm)